# IBM WORKLIGHT SQL Server 2008

Tags: jdbc, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to use SQL adapter with IBM worklight and the SQL Server adapter.
I am running to error:-

```
{
   "errors": [
      "Runtime: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver<\/driverClass not found in Worklight platform or project \/SQLAdapterTest"
   ],
   "info": [
   ],
   "isSuccessful": false,
   "warnings": [
   ]
}
```

Things I ensured:-
a. "sqljdbc4.jar" file in the <>\server\lib
b. included the SQL Server in the worklight properties file

## wl.db.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=MyDB

Any help much appreciated!!

Many Thanks rb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the question with the error you see in Eclipse > Views > Console > Worklight Development Server.

In addition,
In your adapter-name.xml, verify you have updated the default

> `<driverClass>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClass>`

With

> `<driverClass>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driverClass>`

Also, the URL structure seems wrong to me; I think that for MS SQL it should be like this:

> `<url>jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\SQLEXPRESS:1433;databaseName=MyDb;`

Comment: Thanks Idan. I could work it now. An oversight and the XML tag /driverclass was there while editing via eclipse textbox :( Appreciate your help a lot. It just made me go through what you advised. Moreover I have been following your responses to others and so it definitely helped. Cheers rb